# Static news page has for thumbnail the featured image of the first posts

Tags: post-thumbnails, homepage

So I have a static page for the news page in wordpress, and its featured image as a breadcrumb image. I query it with this: `<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(get_option('page_for_posts')); ?>`. The problem is this function for whatever reason outputs the featured image of the first post instead of the featured image for the posts page.

My entire `home.php` looks like this (with irrelevant html code cut out)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(get_option('page_for_posts')); ?>

<?php
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

<!-- code for the posts -->

<?php
  endwhile; endif;
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: are you using a static front page? do you have a 'page for posts' set?

Comment: ps: consider to use `'page_on_front'`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference

Comment: Yes, I have both static front page which is handled by front_page.php, and a page for posts set (handled by home.php). The issue occurs on the posts page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_post_thumnbail()` doesn't accept an arbitrary post id as an argument. It just takes a size to display. To get the post thumbnail URL of a given post, you need to use `get_the_post_thimbnail_url()`:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ), 'full' ); ?>
```